# How to fix problem of site breaking while minimizing the browsers?

Tags: css, cross-browser

I do not have good knowledge in CSS. I have a site developed in WP. When the browser is minimized, the site id broken down. The sidebar go back of the content. I have used the min-width, max-width and width for the divs used but still does not work. Can any one help.

Here the css written

```
@media (max-width: 800px) { /* Simplify the basic layout */ html,body{width:940px;}
#page{max-width:940px;}
#main{margin:0;padding:0;width:100%;}
#access .menu{}
#access a{}
#content{margin:0;padding:0 0 64px;width:640px;} .home #main
#content{margin:0;}
#nav-below{border-bottom:none;margin-bottom:0;}
#main #primary{float:left;margin:0 0 0 80px;width:640px;padding:0;} .home #main #primary,.home #main #primary
#content{float:left;margin:0;padding:0;width:940px;}
#content #nav-below{padding:0;}
#main #secondary{margin:0;padding:78px 0 64px 20px;width:200px;float:left;}
#supplementary{margin:0;padding:34px 0 0;}
#site-generator{margin:0;padding:0 0 0 80px;}
#colophon #supplementary
#first.widget-area{float:left;margin:0;width:700px;padding:0;}
#colophon #supplementary #second.widget-area{float:left;padding:5px 0 0 20px;width:200px;} }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please provide more specifics. Which browsers are you talking about?

Comment: @nfechner:: Thanks for the reply. The problem is with all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
html,body {min-width:940px}
```

Comment: hi. i have exactly the same issue and the problem with this kind of style is that it's gonna make every element in the web page smaller like font-size and images and totally i don't think it's a good solution for these kind of problems. the problem is my web page only breaks in Google Chrome and not in other browsers like Mozilla Firefox when you minimize browser's size which is really interesting for me.